# Save JSON File Locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, client-side

I am designing an HTML5 website that allows you to create and position shapes with several attributes. The shapes are created as divs of class="shape" and the attributes are stored to each shape div using the data method. I'd like to be able to save the position and attributes of the shapes, in a JSON file, with a user defined name.

Currently, I am using ajax and php to generate the JSON file and save it on the server.

Any ideas or thoughts on how it should be done? Bonus points for libraries, APIs and examples!

Clarification Edit: Saving to a discrete file in a user-defined location would be preferable. However, depending on the difficulty factor between the two options, browser storage could certainly suffice.

Comment: Look up localstorage and save the json object into the browsers local store. Keep in mind that this means if they sign in from elsewhere they won't have access to their data.

Comment: _"Currently, I am using ajax and php to generate the JSON file and save it on the server."_ Is requirement for client to provide name to `json` file ? For client to save file ?

Comment: Yes, it is a requirement to be able to specify name. The 'save file' is a bit of a toss up - a discrete file would be preferable though.

Answer (score 3):

I guess there are a lot of possibilities, but one is to use local storage and build some kind of syncronization with your current application. You can sync it with ajax or websockets or so on.

```
var updateLocalData = function(data){
    if( supports_html5_storage() ){
        localStorage.setItem('shape', JSON.stringify(data))
    }
}
```

to sync your data get the written localStorage stuff and send it with your prefered method. And also keep in mind to use any kind of timestamp to always be able to find the latest version.

```
var getLocalData = function(){
    if( supports_html5_storage() ){
        var userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shape'));
        if(userData !== null){
            return userData;
        }
    }
    var tStamp = getCurrentTimeStamp()+"";
    var obj = {};
    obj[tStamp] = {"shapedata": ... };
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

html

```
<input id="filename" type="text" placeholder="Please enter filename" />
<button for="filename">click</button><a id="download" download="" href=""></a>
<br />
<div class="shape"></div>
```

css

```
#download {
    display:none;
}
```

js

```
    $("[for=filename]").on("click", function (e) {
        var shape = $(".shape"),
            // provide `name` if no `input` `value`
            name = $("#filename").val() || "data-" + $.now(),
            url = /*  `request` `url` */;
        // element data stuff
        shape.data("style", shape.css(["color", "width", "height"]));
        var request = function (url, filename) {
            var file = JSON.stringify(shape.data("style"));
            return $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function (jqxhr, settings) {
                    // `name`
                    jqxhr.filename = filename;
                },
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: file
            })
            .then(function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
                $("a#download").attr({
                    "download": jqxhr.filename + ".json",
                        "href": "data:application/json;charset=utf8;base64," 
                                + window.btoa(JSON.stringify(data))
                }).get(0).click();
            }, function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown)
            });
        };
        request(url, name)
    });
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/7rhs55k6/

See [`<a>` Attributes download](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes)

```js
$(function () {
    $("[for=filename]").on("click", function (e) {
        var shape = $(".shape"),
            name = $("#filename").val() || "data-" + $.now(),
            url = "";
        shape.data("style", shape.css(["color", "width", "height"]));
        var request = function (url, filename) {
            var file = JSON.stringify(shape.data("style"));
            return $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function (jqxhr, settings) {
                    jqxhr.filename = filename;
                },
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: file
            }).always(function (jqxhr) {
                    $("a#download").attr({
                        "download": jqxhr.filename + ".json",
                            "href": "data:application/json;charset=utf8;base64," 
                                    + window.btoa(this.data)
                    }).get(0).click();
             });
        };
        request(url, name)
    });
})
```

```css
#download {
    display:none;
}
.shape {
    color:green;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="filename" type="text" placeholder="Please enter filename" />
<button for="filename">click</button><a id="download" download="" href=""></a>
<br />
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to get this code to run locally or on a server and [I'm not having much luck](http://jessewalton.myweb.usf.edu/). The code works on both this page and jsFiddle, even though the url attribute is set to "" and "/echo/json/" respectively, so I'm not sure what that should be set to?

Comment: @JesseWalton At the linked page 1) the `js` piece appears to be wrapped in _two_ `$(function() { $(function() {` calls; 2) jsfiddle is `echo`ing the `json` provided at `data` ; 3) at stacksnippets , the response is actually returning an `error` at `.always` ,  though extracted the sent `data` from `this.data` to demonstrate piece - as stacksnippets does not `echo` response; 4) piece at link is returning `html` - not `json` , which is expected by use of `dataType` option; see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ .  Can post _"ajax and php to generate the JSON file and save it on the server."_  ?